# Booting macOS 11.7 into recovery

Tags: ios

I can't boot into local recovery running macOS 11.7.10
I have tried many things and reinstalled the os twice, last time a clean install.
The recovery volume is present and sound, just I can't boot into it.
Cmd + R gives a black screen whilst all other key combinations boot me into Internet recovery.

Comment: Internet Recovery and the local recovery is the same thing.   What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Allan They're not.  Local recovery comes from a partition on the local storage.

Comment: What specific Mac is it? It makes a difference.

Comment: I’m not referring to it to its physical location @MarcWilson, I’m referring to what gets downloaded versus what gets installed. It’s the same operating system. It still doesn’t change the fact we don’t know what the opiate wants to do with recovery right after installing the clean version of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue as follows:

I erased the Recovery volume: diskutil eraseVolume apfs drive /dev/disk1s3
and reinstalled Big Sur

Problem solved!